# Flume Event Header- add timestamp

Tags: flume

I have a problem with adding time-stamp to flume header. Here is a snipped from my conf file.

```
agent.sources.avrosource.interceptors.addTimestamp.type = org.apache.flume.interceptor.TimestampInterceptor$Builder
```

When I debug with maven, I see that timestamp is not added to header. Here is the debug output:

```
2013-12-05 10:56:34,963 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [DEBUG - com.btoddb.flume.sinks.cassandra.CassandraSink.process(CassandraSink.java:135)] event: [Event headers = {key=value}, body.length = 12 ]
```

FYI, I also add timestamp like this, but again it does not work.

```
agent.sources.avrosource.interceptors = addTime
agent.sources.avrosource.interceptors.addTime.type = timestamp
```

Any help would be apprecited. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you have this useLocalTimeStamp on the sink, it has to work.

agent.sinks.sinkdest.hdfs.useLocalTimeStamp = true